# Loading Xamarin Solution Locks Visual Studio After Update

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 with Xamarin, and I recently updated from Xamarin 4.9.0.752 to Xamarin 4.9.0.753.

After the update, when loading the Solution, the PCL and Android projects appear to finish loading but the iOS and UWP projects never finish. In case there was an issue with either one of these projects, I removed the references to them in the .sln file manually and tried loading the Solution again with no change. The Solution appeared to load the PCL and Android projects but Visual Studio still hangs.

Alongside updating Xamarin, I also updated iPhone Simulator - even though I've never used that yet - but I can't find the version.

Any advice on what to do or try?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try and repair visual studio?

Comment: @KenTucker Nope, but updating to use Visual Studio 2017 removed the issue for me (as per my answer below). :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin instead.

Using VS2017 instead of VS2015 was the quickest fix for me. Perhaps the latest Xamarin has some incompatibilities with VS2015. It would be good to understand what exactly the issue is, so please add a comment if you know. I'm personally not going to dig into the issue because it's a non-issue for me now.

Thanks! :)